# What is a CompoundCallable?

Tags: java, python, scripting, ignition

I'm working with python scripts in Inductive Automation's Ignition HMI (java backend) software. I'm trying to write a script that locates other scripts that are tied to certain objects. Currently I have

```
 result = window.getRootContainer().getComponent("Group 1").getComponent("TheObject").mouseClicked
```

which gets the window displaying my object, enters the root container of that object, then the group that the object is in and then finally the script tied to the mouseClicked event on TheObject. When I run this and print the result, I don't get an error, but:

```
<CompoundCallable with 0 callables>
```

Has anyone seen this before? Does anyone know what I may need to change in my first line of code to access the actual data stored in the mouseClicked script?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no code associated with the `mouseClicked` event of that object.

`CompoundCallable` is a "composition of callables", something callable that calls multiple callables - kind of a callable container. It is used to allow registering multiple functions to be called in a single event handler.

However your `CompoundCallable` contains *zero* callables. That means nothing will be called if you call it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, I don't believe you'll be able to access the data that is in that script (variables, etc.). You could have the mouseClicked script write data to something else in order to access data. There are multiple possibilities for that: Custom Window Property, Custom Component Property, or a tag.